# Netbeans: PhpDoc formatting

Tags: php, netbeans, phpdoc

How to automatically format PhpDoc comments in Netbeans?

I'd like to have comments aligned like this:

```
 * @author      Author Name <example@example.com>
 * @package     Doctrine
 * @subpackage  Table
 * @license     http://www.opensource.org/licenses/lgpl-license.php LGPL
 * @version     $Revision: 67999 $
 * @link        www.phpdoctrine.org
 * @since       1.0
```

When I type  `/**[Enter]` in Netbeans, it automatically imports all parameters as `@param` from the method definition. But then, when the comment is already generated I add a new variable to the definition. What now? How to trigger comment reparse and add newly added parameter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible in current version. I just use `TAB` to align the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work, but its a formatter that allows you to create a custom profile where you dictate the spacing/indentation of everything from your comment blocks to your class, field, methods declarations. It allows you to be able to hit Ctrl+F to have your code automatically format according to what you specify in your profile. Great way of maintaining the appearance of your code for readability without the manual labor involved.

http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/pdt-tools/